# User Control with checkbox in repeater

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, checkbox, repeater

I am a newb to C#/asp. I am trying to add a checkbox to a repeater control within a User Control. When a user clicks the checkbox I want to capture that event on the page that the user control is on. I have gotten as far as putting the checkbox in the repeater.
Here is what I have in the User control.

```
       <asp:Repeater ID="rOrderItems" runat="server" ><HeaderTemplate>
            <table class="mGrid" ><tr><td width="50%" align="left" >Item</td>
            <td width="20%" align="right">Qty</td>
            <td width="20%" align="center">Remove</td></td></tr></HeaderTemplate>                

            <ItemTemplate >
                <tr>
                <td> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "item.ItemNumber")%> </td>
                <td> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Quantity")%> </td>
                 <td> <asp:CheckBox  ID="cbxRemove" AutoPostBack="true" Checked="false" OnCheckedChanged="cbxRemove_CheckedChanged"  runat="server" /></td> 
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate><tr><td>   </td><td>  </td></tr></table>
            </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

I am a bit lost after this. Forgive me my ignorance but I am learning.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to loop through to remove the check items. Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rOrderItems.Items.Count; i++) {
  CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)rOrderItems.Items[i].FindControl("cbxRemove");
  if (chk.Checked) {
    //remove this item
  }
}
```

Let me know how that works.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for but not quite sure where it goes.

Comment: Would this be in the user control code behind or the page using the user control this is in?

Comment: It looks like you are triggering the function `cbxRemove_CheckedChanged`. Is that getting called? You can check by putting a breakpoint on the first line inside the function.

Comment: It would be in the code behind of the user control, assuming the markup you have posted is part of the user control.